# SDL OpenGL Code Appears To Have No Depth

Tags: windows, opengl, sdl, codeblocks

I am running this code on a PC (compiled in code::blocks 10.05)

 When i used to do basic OpenGL code with GLUT (GL Utiltiy Toolkit) Everything worked fine.

 Now that i'm running OpenGL code through the SDL Framework when i try to change the z-axis (third parameter) of the translation function the location of a geometric primitive (quad) the 3D space appears to have no depth and either shows covering the complete screen or completely disappears when the depth gets to a certain point. 
Am i missing anything? :/

```
#include <sdl.h>
#include <string>
#include "sdl_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_opengl.h"
#include <gl\gl.h>
// Declare Constants
const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;
// Create Event Listener
SDL_Event event;
// Declare Variable Used To Control How Deep Into The Screen The Quad Is
GLfloat zpos(0);
// Loop Switches
bool gamestarted(false);
bool exited(false);
// Prototype For My GL Draw Function
void drawstuff();

// Code Begins

void init_GL() {
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                        // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                         // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                        // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                     // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);          // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 513);                     // Viewport Change
    glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 513, -1.0, 1.0);                 // Puts Stuff Into View
}
bool init() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 513, 32, SDL_OPENGL);
    return true;
}  
void drawstuff() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, zpos);
    glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}
int main (int argc, char* args[]) {
    init();
    init_GL();
    while(exited == false) {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ) {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                exited = true;
            }
            if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ) {
                zpos-=.1;
            }
        }
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        drawstuff();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
        }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say depth, do you refer to a perspective effect? You need to use a perspective projection matrix (see gluPerspective) if you want things farther away to appear smaller.

You're currently using orthographic projection (glOrtho), which does not have any perspective effect.

Comment: i tried doing that and it didn't work. Am i missing something? Thanks for your help by the way!! 
So far i tried deleting the line with the glOrtho call and replacing it with "gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)640/(GLfloat)513,0.1f,100.0f);"

Comment: nevermind it worked once i did that, changed it to a perspective (as shown in comment above) and decremented the variable by 1 instead of .1 and i could see that it worked. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for your problem, but I find a problem in your code.
After rendering one frame, you cleared the color framebuffer, but you forgot to clear the depth buffer.So, use glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); in your main function and see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the anwser:

In Orthographic projection(after projection and perspective divide):

Zb = -2/(f-n) -(f+n)/((f-n)*Z)

Zb:z value in depth buffer

Z: z value of your vertex you give

In your situation: glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 513, -1.0, 1.0);
f = 1.0, n = -1.0
so your Zb would always be -2/(f - n) = -1, this causes all your primitives's depth the same.

You can reference to Red book's Appendix C.2.5.There is a matrix for orthographic projection, and after that is perspective divide.
There is another tips to keep in mind in perspective projection that zNear value cannot be set to zero, which causes all primitives' depth value in depth buffer to be same as this one.